# How do I define a right arrow with bar in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

could any one tell me how I can define the following symbol in Latex please?
It looks like an implies symbol concatenated with a vertical bar.

[image]

Comment: Might want to try http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html otherwise I'm not too sure

Comment: For what it's worth, the symbol does not seem to exist in unicode. Unless they have given it a *really* counter-intuitive name.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `stmaryrd` font has `\mapsfromchar`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\newcommand{\Rightarrowbar}{\Rightarrow\mapsfromchar}
\newcommand{\Leftarrowbar}{\mapstochar\Leftarrow}

\begin{document}

$a\Rightarrowbar b$

$a\Leftarrowbar b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If `stmaryrd` is not an option for you, it's possible to reflect `\mapstochar`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\fakedmapsfromchar}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\reflectmathchar\mapstochar}%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\reflectmathchar}[2]{%
  \reflectbox{$\m@th#1#2$}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\Rightarrowbar}{\Rightarrow\fakedmapsfromchar}
\newcommand{\Leftarrowbar}{\mapstochar\Leftarrow}

\begin{document}

$a\Rightarrowbar b$

$a\Leftarrowbar b$

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\myRightarrow}{\mathrel{{\Longrightarrow}\!\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptscriptstyle|$}}}}

\begin{document}

$ A \myRightarrow B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Edit*: 
 If you want the final bar to have the same width as the \Rightarrow, you can use two consecutive `|` with some kerning between them:

```
\newcommand{\myvarRightarrow}{\mathrel{{ =⇒ }\!\vcenter{\hbox{$ \scriptscriptstyle|\mkern-5.4mu|$}}}}
```

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this have uneven stroke widths due to scaling the bar part?

Comment: That's right. I propose a work-around in my update.

Answer (score 8):

One can always build a symbol by himself (thanks to [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter), this is a scalable version):

```
\documentclass[margin=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand{\yoursymbol}{\mathbin{\Rightarrow\hspace{-0.45em}\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{0.8}{$\shortmid$}}}}}
\begin{document}
$1\yoursymbol2$ {\Huge $1\yoursymbol2$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

> **Caution**: This doesn't work in subscript. I'm trying to find some solution...

Comment: If you use a unit that scales with the font, this will also work with other font sizes. For example `\hspace{-0.45em}` instead of `\hspace{-4.3pt}`

Comment: @samcarter Added! Thank you very much!